# How to add a checkbox and bindining it in this ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

I have a ListView in the Quiz Management web-based application that I am developing and I am binding it to the Answers table in the Database. Now, I want to add a column with a CheckBox control that will be bound to (isCorrect) column in the QuizContent table in the database. I don't know how to do that, so could you please help me in this?

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID, isCorrect
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
Question Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
```

My ASP.NET code:

```
<div align="center">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
            DataKeyNames="AnswerID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                            Text='<%# Bind("isCorrect") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table id="Table2" runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("isCorrect") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="IsCorrectLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isCorrect") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer</th>
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">is Correct?</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                </table></div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="isCorrectLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("isCorrect") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT        AnswerID, Answer
                            FROM            Answers
                            WHERE        (AnswerID IN
                                                         (SELECT DISTINCT AnswerID
                                                           FROM            QuizContent
                                                           WHERE        (QuestionID = @QuestionID)))"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Answers] WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Answers] ([Answer]) VALUES (@Answer)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Answers] SET [Answer] = @Answer WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" DefaultValue="0"
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Again, my problem is having two different tables in the database. The ListView is bound to the Answer table. And for the CheckBox, it has to be bound to the second table which is the QuizContent, **so how to do that?**

**UPDATE:**

Here's a snapshot to show you what I am missing in the code:
[image]

Comment: do you get the table data or you have problem in getting table data or problem in biding the data with the ischeckbox column ?

Comment: I think you should move the `isCorrect` column from the _QuizContent_ table to the _Answers_ table. That would make things easier. Unless I'm missing something it seems a good improvement

Comment: I am having a problem with adding the checkbox and binding it to the database, so how to do it?

Comment: Actually, it is better to keep it under QuizContent table because in the Answer table it will be difficult to map it with the question. Besides that, I may have more than one question having a (True or False) as possible answers.

Comment: I gtg to sleep, can you tell me the goal of the application you are building before I leave, maybe I can help you with a better design to make things easier. My understanding is: You have Quiz containing Questions, which in turn contain answers. Now each Question can have more than one valid answer? (for example if the user needs to select more than one answer to consider it valid). And since a Quiz can have multiple Questions, to determine if the Quiz is valid you need to make sure all Questions (or some %) are correct right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the query of the `SqlDatasource3` does the trick

[image]

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT        Answers.*, QuizContent.IsCorrect
FROM            Answers INNER JOIN
                         QuizContent ON Answers.AnswerID = QuizContent.AnswerID
WHERE        (QuizContent.QuestionID = @QuestionID)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your continuous help. However, what about INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that, that's why I suggested you to  move the isCorrect column from the QuizContent table to the Answers table. Is that possible? if not, you would need to use Store Procedures

Comment: I just replied to your comment under the question. Please see it.

Comment: OK. Could you please provide me with a hint or a sample code about how to utilize the Store Procedures in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Change your sqldatasource3 select statement as

```
SELECT        AnswerID, Answer
                        FROM            Answers
                        WHERE        (AnswerID IN
                                                     (SELECT DISTINCT AnswerID
                                                       FROM            QuizContent
                                                       WHERE        (QuestionID = @QuestionID)))

UNION ALL 
SELECT AnswerID,isCorrect from QuizContent 
WHERE Answers.AnswerID = QuizContent.AnswerID
```

Comment: Could you please help me in adding the CheckBox to this ListView and how to bind its value to the database?

Comment: @TechnologyLover what help you needed ?

Comment: @TechnologyLover to use a storedprocedure in a sql datasrouce specify the name of storedprocedure and set SelectCommandType in the select command like this `SelectCommand="storedprocedureName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"`

Comment: thanks for your continuous help. I am still struggling with inserting Answers into Answers Table and the checkbox did not work with me and I don't know why. There is no error messages but I cannot insert any answer to the Answers table in the third ListView.